# How can make peer to peer video chat using tornado webserver

Tags: python, node.js, tornado, webrtc

I see a lot of example for making peer to peer video chat using nodejs and webrtc. I am searching a good video chat demo using tornado websever.

Is it possible to make a video chat using tornado webserver and webrtc?

I am new to html5 and webrtc.

If you find any example/demos please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

WebRTC is a client-side technology and will work regardless of your server. The basic idea is that WebRTC lets you capture a media stream (such as  a  video stream), and then generate a token that represents this stream. You then use your server to relay this token to another user. The browser that receives this token can use the token to generate a URL that can be used as the `src` attribute of a `<video>` or `<audio>` tag (depending on what kind of media stream you captured), and setting the src attribute to this URL causes the second browser to talk directly to the first browser to stream this data.

There are more details and code snippets on the [html5rocks WebRTC page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/).

Comment: Hi Michael .. Thank you for the replay .. Did you find any demos/examples